# Why does sapply() return a list with attributes when used on characters?

Tags: r, sapply

There is a strange behaviour of `sapply()` when used on a vector of characters:

```
y <- c("Hello", "bob", "daN")
z <- sapply(y, function(x) {toupper(x)})
z
# Hello     bob     daN 
# "HELLO"   "BOB"   "DAN" 
str(z)
# Named chr [1:3] "HELLO" "BOB" "DAN"
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Hello" "bob" "daN"
```

Why does `sapply()` return a vector with the old values as attributes? I don't want them, I don't need them and I am not aware of this behaviour when applied on e.g. numerical vectors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, `sapply()` adds names for each iteration on character vectors.
The result can be delivered without the names by using `USE.NAMES = FALSE` in the call.

```
sapply(y, toupper, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] "HELLO" "BOB"   "DAN"
```

This is explained in `help(sapply)`

> **USE.NAMES** - logical; if TRUE and if X is character, use X as names for the result unless it had names already. Since this argument follows ... its name cannot be abbreviated.

**Note** that when you are applying a single function only, there is no need to use an anonymous function (anonymous function usage is also slightly less efficient).  This is also shown above.

**Also note** that `sapply()` is not necessary here, as `toupper()` is vectorized.

```
toupper(y)
# [1] "HELLO" "BOB"   "DAN"
```

Comment: I was reading this documentation but I didn't understand it. Now I do.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "anonymous function"?

Comment: Sure.  When you wrote `function(x) { toupper(x) }` you were using an "anonymous function" because that function is not assigned a name.  You could write it in the console like this `(function(x) toupper(x))(y)` and get a result without assigning the function a name.

Comment: Perfect! I've been searching for this for days. At first, I thought I was getting duplicate rows but it turns out that these were names, and the names were being derived from the source row's value.